# Google Maps collapse issue in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using bootstrap 3 and have a container as follows:

```
<div class="box-content" id="ToolsContainer">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Access</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="home"></div>
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
          <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div?
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue i am facing is the the div that contains the map contains a google map. however the map appears collapsed.

Any ideas why it might not be rendering correctly?

Comment: Can you post your CSS and/or make a jsfiddle please?

Comment: my CSS is the same as that comes default with bootstrap except with some styles changed.

Comment: Well then please post it or I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

`100%` height won't work unless the map's containers are also `100%`..

```
html, body, .container, .tab-content, .tab-pane  {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or, you can specify a pixel height for the map..

```
#map {
  width:100%;
  height:480px;
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/119078

Comment: I am appending the map div on a button click and i added height to be 480px but still does not work.